# Comparing the minimum squared Mahalanobis norm of $n$ [orthonormal vs. i.i.d] random unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices

Let $Q$ diagonal with coefficients $q_1 \geq ... \geq q_n \geq 0$.
Let $U = \left[ u_1 ~ ... ~ u_n \right]$ distributed uniformly on the set of $n \times n$ orthonormal matrices, and $\tilde{u}_1, ..., \tilde{u}_n$ distributed i.i.d uniformly on the $\ell_2$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In other words $\tilde{u}_j$ are independent copies of the $u_j$.

Does the following hold:
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E} \min_{j \leq n} u_j^\top Q u_j \leq c \cdot \mathbb{E} \min_{j \leq n} \tilde{u}_j^\top Q \tilde{u}_j
\end{equation}
where $c>0$ is a universal constant?

Numerically it seems that yes, with $c=1$. Moreover numerically it seems that the first is dominated by the second even in CDF, and even with any number of vectors smaller than the dimension: for any $1 \leq k \leq n$,
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P}\left(
        \min_{j \leq k} u_j^\top Q u_j > x
\right)
    \leq \mathbb{P}\left(
        \min_{j \leq k} \tilde{u}_j^\top Q \tilde{u}_j > x
    \right).
\end{equation}
(But I'm mainly concerned with the inequality in expectation and for $k=n$.)